# Obtaining File (pdf) object from Storage Access Framework to upload to server

Tags: android, file, retrofit2, uri, storage-access-framework

In the application the user is allowed to choose a PDF file using Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT), which opens android's built in file selector, and i set the type to PDF so only PDF's can be chosen. After the user selects the PDF, i'm obtaining a URI. My question is, how can i obtain the File object with this URI? This file is a document in public directories (such as downloads, documents etc). So, as explained here:

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files/external-scoped

I must use the Storage Access Framework. I use this framework, but then again the example shown is only for Bitmap:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider#open-client

"Once you have the URI for a document, you can open it or do whatever else you want to do with it." The example shown is for a Bitmap only, not for a File object (which i need to upload to server).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You do not need a FIle object at all. If you had a FIle object you would probably open a FIleInputStream to read the contents. Those times are over. You now just open an InputStream is = getContentResolver().OpenInputStream(uri); The rest of the code is the same.

Comment: how do i use that inputstream to upload using retrofit though? most retrofit tutorials use a File object

Comment: It looks strange to me that a widely used product like retrofit cannot upload from a content scheme. The developers could add it in five minutes.

Comment: i ended up using 'org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils' method : copyInputStreamToFile to pass inputstream into a local temp file (File file = new File(getBaseContext().getFilesDir(), "temp.pdf")